# Axapta: WinAPI::shellExecute no longer work

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Previously, WinAPI::shellExecute() is working on AX 2009, but I do not know why, after updating AX kernel and application to version 5.0.1500.1313, WinAPI::shellExecute() is no longer working, or did someone change settings or what is actually prevent it from working?

The symptom is the target EXE actually executed but it is being shutdown again very quick.

Could anyone help to analyze this problem and give solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to upgrade to roll-up 7 (5.0.1500.4570).

You could do a kernel upgrade only.

Comment: Jan, actually I'm not sure is it because of upgrade or other settings problem, could you please give me explanation whether this is really because of the version I'm using with?.Basically it is still allowed to use WinAPI::shellExecute() right? And this problem is not common right?

Comment: Unless you send me your server, I can only can give you hints. `ShellExecute` is okay (on the client, not the server). Common, I have no statistics.

Comment: Jan, it's still not working after I've update to roll up 7, I think the problem is something else (It definitely run on client). I even try to use System.Diagnostic.Process to no avail. Is there any settings on axapta which prevent it's client from executing? As I'd said before the program I wanna run (a finger print scanner) actually run, but immediately closed again. The prove it is being executed is, I create a VBScript which display message Box before and after executing the EXE, when execute both box open and I even seen a splash of the finger print window, can you help me why?

Comment: There is no AX options regarding `ShellExecute` so I expect external forces are in place. Maybe your finger print scanner crashes? Maybe your anti-virus does not like your scanner program? Try setting the waitForCompletion parameter to true.